# Prevent __TypeId__ to be used in Spring Cloud Stream

Tags: spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

We had a rogue producer setting a Kafka Header `__TypeId__` to a class that was part of the producer, but not of a consumer implemented within a *Spring Cloud Stream* application using *Kafka Streams* binder. It resulted in an exception
`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The class 'com.bad.MyClass' is not in the trusted packages: [java.util, java.lang, de.datev.pws.loon.dcp.foreignmodels.*]. If you believe this class is safe to deserialize, please provide its name. If the serialization is only done by a trusted source, you can also enable trust all (*).`

**How can we ensure within the consumer that this TypeId header is ignored?**

Some stackoverflow answers point to `spring.json.use.type.headers=false`, but it seems to be an "old" property, that is no more valid.

application.yaml:

```yaml
spring:
  json.use.type.headers: false
  application:
    name: dcp-all
  kafka:
    bootstrap-servers: 'xxxxx.kafka.dev.dvint.de:9093'
  cloud:
    stream:
      kafka:
        streams:
          binder:
            required-acks: -1 # all in-sync-replicas

...
```

Stack trace:

```
    at org.springframework.kafka.support.mapping.DefaultJackson2JavaTypeMapper.getClassIdType(DefaultJackson2JavaTypeMapper.java:129)
    at org.springframework.kafka.support.mapping.DefaultJackson2JavaTypeMapper.toJavaType(DefaultJackson2JavaTypeMapper.java:103)
    at org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer.deserialize(JsonDeserializer.java:569)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.SourceNode.deserializeValue(SourceNode.java:58)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.RecordDeserializer.deserialize(RecordDeserializer.java:66)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.RecordQueue.updateHead(RecordQueue.java:176)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.RecordQueue.addRawRecords(RecordQueue.java:112)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.PartitionGroup.addRawRecords(PartitionGroup.java:304)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.addRecords(StreamTask.java:960)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.TaskManager.addRecordsToTasks(TaskManager.java:1068)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.pollPhase(StreamThread.java:962)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runOnce(StreamThread.java:751)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runLoop(StreamThread.java:604)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.run(StreamThread.java:576)
```

Here is a unit test

```java
    @Test
    void consumeWorksEvenWithBadTypesHeader() throws JsonProcessingException, InterruptedException {
        Map<String, Object> producerProps = KafkaTestUtils.producerProps(embeddedKafka);
        producerProps.put("key.serializer", StringSerializer.class.getName());
        DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<String, String> pf = new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(producerProps);

        List<Header> headers = Arrays.asList(new RecordHeader("__TypeId__", "com.bad.MyClass".getBytes()));
        ProducerRecord<String,String> p = new ProducerRecord(TOPIC1, 0, "any-key",
            "{ ... some valid JSON ...}", headers);

        try {
            KafkaTemplate<String, String> template = new KafkaTemplate<>(pf, true);
            template.send(p);

            ConsumerRecord<String, String> consumerRecord = KafkaTestUtils.getSingleRecord(consumer, TOPIC2, DEFAULT_CONSUMER_POLL_TIME);

            // Assertions ...
        } finally {
            pf.destroy();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 options:

1. On the producer side set the property to omit adding the type info headers
2. On the consumer side, set the property to not use the type info headers

https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#json-serde

It is not an "old" property.

```java
    /**
     * Kafka config property for using type headers (default true).
     * @since 2.2.3
     */
    public static final String USE_TYPE_INFO_HEADERS = "spring.json.use.type.headers";
```

It needs to be set in the consumer properties.

Comment: Strange. My IDE (properly configured for Spring properties) tells me "Cannot resolve configuration property 'spring.json.use.type.headers'" and even with header=false my unit test fails. I am on Spring Boot 2.6.3 and Cloud 2021.0.0. Any idea?

Comment: Show exactly how you are setting the property (edit the question if using YAML).

Comment: I have added the stack trace above, When I set a breakpoint in org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer.deserialize then this.typeMapper.getTypePrecedence().equals(TypePrecedence.TYPE_ID) is true.

Comment: It is not a top level property like that; it needs to be passed into the consumer config. See https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/docs/3.2.1/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka.html#_kafka_streams_binder_properties `spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.binder.consumerProperties.spring.json.use.type.headers: false`.

Comment: Thanks! It was `spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.binder.configuration.spring.json.use.type.headers: false`, because we are using the Kafka Streams binder.

Comment: Yes, I changed my comment to add the `.streams` - however, putting it in the `configuration` means it will be added to the producer config too (which might log a warning about an unknown property). It's best to add it explicitly for the consumer only.

Comment: @GaryRussell, how can we ignore the headers with a consumer annotated with KafkaListener ? Should we create consumer factory and add the ignore parameter?

Comment: Don't ask questions in comments on old answers. The property has nothing to do with the listener configuration, it is a consumer property configured on the consumer factory. If that's not clear, ask a new question with much more context and information about what you don't understand.

Comment: New question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75535333/ignore-kafka-message-type-headers