# Ignore Kafka message type headers

Tags: java, spring-kafka

I have a kafka consumer in which I want to ignore the type headers, I have added the config, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
@KafkaListener(topics = ["\${app.kafka.upstream-topic}"])
fun listen(
    @Header(name = RECEIVED_MESSAGE_KEY) key: Id,
    @Payload(required = false) payload: Employee?,
    ack: Acknowledgment
)
```

Configurations:

```
spring:
application:
  name: @project.artifactId@
config:
  import: bootstrap.yml
main:
  banner-mode: "off"
jmx:
  enabled: true
kafka:
  consumer:
    key-deserializer: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer
    value-deserializer: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer
    auto-offset-reset: earliest
    group-id: ${spring.application.name}.${stage}
    properties:
      spring.json.use.type.headers: false
```

Stacktrace:

`com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token 'eyJ0YXJnZXQtcHJvdG9jb2wiOiJqYXZhLmxhbmcuU3RyaW5nIn0': was expecting (JSON String, Number, Array, Object or token 'null', 'true' or 'false') at [Source: (byte[])"eyJ0YXJnZXQtcHJvdG9jb2wiOiJqYXZhLmxhbmcuU3RyaW5nIn0="; line: 1, column: 53] at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser._constructError(JsonParser.java:2391) at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportError(ParserMinimalBase.java:745) at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._reportInvalidToken(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:3635) at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._handleUnexpectedValue(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:2734) at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._nextTokenNotInObject(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:902) at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser.nextToken(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:794) at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._initForReading(ObjectMapper.java:4761) at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4667) at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3690) at org.springframework.kafka.support.DefaultKafkaHeaderMapper.decodeJsonTypes(DefaultKafkaHeaderMapper.java:396) at org.springframework.kafka.support.DefaultKafkaHeaderMapper.toHeaders(DefaultKafkaHeaderMapper.java:314) at org.springframework.kafka.support.converter.MessagingMessageConverter.mapOrAddHeaders(MessagingMessageConverter.java:188) at org.springframework.kafka.support.converter.MessagingMessageConverter.toMessage(MessagingMessageConverter.java:166) at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.toMessagingMessage(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:322) at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:83) at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:53) at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeOnMessage(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2667) at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeOnMessage(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2647) at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeRecordListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2574) at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeWithRecords(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2454) at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeRecordListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2332) at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2003) at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeIfHaveRecords(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1373) at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.pollAndInvoke(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1364) at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1255) at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)`

Please advice what's wrong.

Comment: That has nothing to do with the type id header; it means the JSON is badly formed. `eyJ0YXJnZXQtcHJvdG9jb2wiOiJqYXZhLmxhbmcuU3RyaW5nIn0` is not valid JSON. You also need to show the complete stack trace. Without it, we don't know if it's the key or value that is invalid.

Comment: Unable to edit my own question to add stack-trace. The stack-trace clearly pointed me to https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/blob/main/spring-kafka/src/main/java/org/springframework/kafka/support/DefaultKafkaHeaderMapper.java#L392
`at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3690)
    at org.springframework.kafka.support.DefaultKafkaHeaderMapper.decodeJsonTypes(DefaultKafkaHeaderMapper.java:396)
    at org.springframework.kafka.support.DefaultKafkaHeaderMapper.toHeaders(DefaultKafkaHeaderMapper.java:314)
`

Comment: I am not sure why you can't edit; but that is a different problem; it means the `spring_json_header_types` header has some garbage in it somehow. The error is logged, but the mapping continues.

Comment: It should contain a JSON map; it is created on the producer side by `target.add(new RecordHeader(JSON_TYPES, headerObjectMapper.writeValueAsBytes(jsonHeaders)));`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You somehow have corruption in the `spring_json_header_types` header.

It should contain a JSON map; it is created on the producer side by

```
final Map<String, String> jsonHeaders = new HashMap<>();
...
target.add(new RecordHeader(JSON_TYPES, headerObjectMapper.writeValueAsBytes(jsonHeaders)));
```

The error is non fatal; it just means the header types could not be restored.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Turned out some messages were corrupted.
I have another [open question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75582041/kafka-type-headers-not-removed-by-producer), pls take a look.