# Kafka Type headers not removed by producer

Tags: spring-kafka

I have spring kafka stream producer from which I don't want to emit the Type headers for consuming applications.
I have added the config right, but doesn't seem to work. The Kafka record still has Type headers.

Config:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: @project.artifactId@
  main:
    banner-mode: "off"
  data:
    mongodb:
      auto-index-creation: false
      uri:  mongodb://localhost:27017/TestDb
  zipkin:
    enabled: false
  sleuth:
    messaging:
      messaging:
        enabled: false
      kafka:
        enabled: false
  jackson:
    serialization:
      write-dates-as-timestamps: true
  cloud:
    stream:
      function:
        definition: processor
      kafka:
        binder:
          brokers: ${spring.embedded.kafka.brokers}
          producerProperties:
            useNativeEncoding: true
            compression.type: lz4
            key.serializer: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer
            value.serializer: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer
            spring.json.add.type.headers: false
```

I use spring-kafka 2.8

Please advice what's wrong.

[image: This is how the record headers look like]

Answer (score 0):

Must be a configuration problem; with

```
'[spring.json.add.type.headers]': true
```

I see the `__TypeId__` headers; when is is false, they are suppressed.

The `spring_json_header_types` has nothing to do with serialization; that is created by the header mapper so the headers can be properly decoded on the consumer side.

To suppress that, add a custom header mapper:

> `spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.headerMapperBeanName`

> The bean name of a `KafkaHeaderMapper` used for mapping `spring-messaging` headers to and from Kafka headers. Use this, for example, if you wish to customize the trusted packages in a `BinderHeaderMapper` bean that uses JSON deserialization for the headers. If this custom `BinderHeaderMapper` bean is not made available to the binder using this property, then the binder will look for a header mapper bean with the name `kafkaBinderHeaderMapper` that is of type `BinderHeaderMapper` before falling back to a default `BinderHeaderMapper` created by the binder.

> Default: none.

spring-kafka provides a `SimpleKafkaHeaderMapper` which does not convey type information for headers.

**EDIT**

Here is my test code/config:

```yaml
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      kafka:
        binder:
          producerProperties:
            useNativeEncoding: true
#            '[compression.type]': lz4
            '[key.serializer]': org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer
            '[value.serializer]': org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer
            '[spring.json.add.type.headers]': false
  kafka:
    consumer:
      auto-offset-reset: earliest
```

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class So75582041Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So75582041Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    ApplicationRunner runner(StreamBridge bridge) {
        return args -> {
            bridge.send("so75582041-out-0", MessageBuilder.withPayload("test").setHeader(KafkaHeaders.MESSAGE_KEY, "foo").build());
        };
    }

    @KafkaListener(id = "so75582041", topics = "so75582041-out-0")
    void listen(ConsumerRecord<?, ?> in) {
        in.headers().forEach(h -> System.out.println("h:" + h.key() + " = " + new String(h.value())));
    }

}
```

Result:

```
h:contentType = application/json
h:target-protocol = kafka
h:spring_json_header_types = {"contentType":"java.lang.String","target-protocol":"java.lang.String"}
```

Comment: I will try out the SimpleKafkaHeaderMapper.

Meanwhile, I wonder if this config `spring.json.add.type.headers` should be added under `spring.cloud.stream.kafka.default.producer.configuration`?

I just happened to come across [this post](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/issues/1182) and got thinking

Comment: The config is correct; I added my test to the answer.

Comment: Ok. my take away is that he config should be wrapped within '[]'
is that right?

Comment: It doesn't make a difference; it's just that my IDE complains about dotted properties. I just retested without the `'[...]'` and it still works.