# How to write Kafka event deserialization unit test which takes event headers into consideration?

Tags: java, apache-kafka

We send events to Kafka as JSON objects and recently we had deserialization errors in prod:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The class 'com.our.company.otherPackage.MyEventClass' is not in the trusted packages: [java.util, java.lang, com.our.company.package]. If you believe this class is safe to deserialize, please provide its name. If the serialization is only done by a trusted source, you can also enable trust all (*).
```

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.our.otherPackage.ImmutableMyEventClass
```

Just in case: events are defined with org.Immutables library, that's why we have here *Immutable* prefix

Our Kafka events have `__TypeId__` header key with value `com.our.company.package.ImmutableMyEventClass`. These headers are considered during deserialization. Kafka event class was moved to other package, and when producer started to send events with `__TypeId__` header value of `com.our.company.otherPackage.ImmutableMyEventClass`, then consumers started to get deserialization errors.

Consumers look like this:

```
@KafkaListener(
        topics = "${com.our.company.topic}",
        containerFactory = "containerFactory")
void onEvent(ConsumerRecord<String, MyEventClass> record) {

}
```

Question: how to write a unit test for deserialization to cover such cases? It would be great to protect ourselves from such cases in future.

I know that we can handle the problem from the other side and make changes to deserializer,

Also, I am leaving this link where with explanation that checking `__TypeId__` can be disabled. Maybe it will be useful for somebody with similar problems: [Prevent __TypeId__ to be used in Spring Cloud Stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70856954/prevent-typeid-to-be-used-in-spring-cloud-stream)

But let's focus on deserialization test with event headers: it would be a useful knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

You should have deprecated the old class and package until the producer no longer was sending those events.

Your only solution now is to skip those events.

Otherwise, tests shouldn't rely on existing topic data, so you'd never catch this error without having both versions of the old and new packages on your classpath, which I'm guessing you want to avoid.